# Parse.com with iOS App and Objective-C code

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfimageview

until recently, I've always used Parse.com for data management of my app I was now working on a new project and I have some problems ....

P.S. I'm using Xcode 6

First there **PFImageView**, you can confirm this? at this point without consulting a PFImageView how can I draw a picture in my app? I do not understand why you can not use in my app PFImageView

Also when I do a query, previously (using the enter button on the keyboard) appeared the auto-build block of the query but now I find myself this

```
  PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
  [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock: (nullable PFArrayResultBlock (nullable) block]
```

What is happening to parse.com? where am I doing wrong? someone can 'give me help on this?

Comment: no one has noticed this problem with parse.com ?? there are ways to figure out what's going on?

Comment: PFQuery *query = [PFUser query]; replace this with PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"]; this might help and get it in backgound like  [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)  {    }}];

Comment: Rory, are you allowing Xcode access to the Internet when it starts up? I know it's basic but please confirm connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't use PFFile instead?

For loading an image from data you can do like this:

```
    PFFile *fileImage = your_file;
    [fileImage getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
       UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
       yourImageView.image = image;
    }];
```

And for the PFQuery replace that method with this block:

```
 [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) { }}];
```

or check the class reference [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html)

Answer (score 2):

**On the PFImageView:**

Try calling `– loadInBackground` on in. [Source](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFImageView.html#//api/name/loadInBackground)

**On autocompletion:**

This seems to be a bug in Xcode actually. After they have implemented the "nullable" keyword, Xcode seems to be having a hard time auto generating code for the blocks you pass as arguments. That has nothing to do with Parse though.