# Parse findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) returning 0 objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm using Parse for quite some time now, and suddenly the findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock has stopped working (returning 0 objects). Even if I use no filters, it still returns 0 objects. I thought maybe the keys were changed but everything looks the same.

The only new difference i've noticed is that when i'm typing findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock it autocompletes to:

```
findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:(nullable PFArrayResultBlock(nullable )block
```

I checked around and saw people say it's only a bug on xcode autocorrect side and nothing with Parse services. [Parse.com with iOS App and Objective-C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923856/parse-com-with-ios-app-and-objective-c-code)

So you'll probably think, maybe i've got no data in my table, so check out the following example:

I'm trying to find a user from the User table with an email that is equal to 'xxx'. It gives me 0 objects. But when I use

```
[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:password:block]
```

I end up with the existing user I logged in with. With the 'xxx' email attribute...

Weird!

Any help?

Comment: Have you checked the ACL and Class-Level-Permissions of the User table? Maybe you disabled the Find operation there?

Comment: Probably permissions.  Can you add some stronger evidence?  Please present the code for the query and proof that the table isn't empty.  Doing a login (without presenting the currentUser state beforehand) is unconvincing.  Please show a table with rows, show its security settings, and show how you measure that the result is empty.